# How to make a carousel like Yolele

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I am trying to create this carousel but I am not able to do it.
Is using a tool like **GSAP **would help it ?

This is the link of the website - "[https://yolele.com](https://yolele.com/)"

I tried using JS but not sure what to do and where to start.